# Solving integral equation with an unknown function under the integral in matlab

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to solve a equations like this:
$\sin(x) = (1 - \int y(x) dx) * y(x) $

whats matlab code for this equation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don’t know matlab. But you asked if ‘it is possible to be solved’, and my answer to that is yes.

Let $u=\frac{\sin x}y$, $u’=\frac{du}{dx}$.

We have
$$u=1-\int\frac{\sin x}{u}dx$$

Differentiating both sides,

$$u’=-\frac{\sin x}u$$
$$\begin{align}
udu&=-\sin x~dx \\
C+\frac{u^2}2&=\cos x\\
u&=\pm\sqrt{C+2\cos x}\\
y&=\pm\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{C+2\cos x}}\\
\end{align}
$$